# How to pass route parameters in FilamentPHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I wanted to pass station id when creating an episode. I did the following changes to my EpisodeResource file.

```
            'edit' => Pages\EditEpisode::route(
                '/{station}/{record}/edit'
            ),
```

The problem with this is that even though my Create & Edit route changed but I cannot update or create operations. Seems like `POST` request to `/livewire/update` doesn't consider the `station` id.

Should I change it to `http query request`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right; Livewire doesn't receive the `station` parameter. So the workaround is you have to set the parameter each time it is empty. Like this (in your case, `EpisodeResource`):

```
public static function getUrl(string $name = 'index', array $parameters = [], bool $isAbsolute = true, ?string $panel = null, ?Model $tenant = null): string
{
    if (!isset($parameters['station'])) {
        $parameters['station'] = self::getCurrentStation(); //Route::current()->parameter('station')
    }

    return parent::getUrl($name, $parameters, $isAbsolute, $panel, $tenant);
}

private static function getCurrentStation()
{
    $station = request('station');
    if(isset($station)){
       return $station;
    }
    
    //try to get the Model from the previous known route
    $previousRoute = Route::getRoutes()->match(request()->create(url()->previousPath()));
    if (isset($previousRoute)) {
        //the model is not in the request (this is probably a Livewire request)
        //reset it
        $station = $previousRoute->parameter('station');
        request()->merge(['station' => $station]);

        return $station;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Please also see this issue: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/7104 and this discussion: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/6099